# loop through two different html tables

Tags: asp-classic

I am searching for the answer for the whole day.

Basically, I have two html tables and a recordset in getrows()

The page is designed so that there are two html tables and I need to generate it, no other choice to re-design the page :(

Here are the html tables. They are horizontally aligned.

```
table1                table2
row                   row
row                   row
row                   row
```

and so on...
How can I generate these tables and of course I do not know how many records are in the recordset.

lets assume that there are 3 fields, name, quantity and date. so, there will be two html tables and i get six columns, three of each table. i will not distribute different fields to different tables. so tables are just the same, side by side, with different data on them, not the fields

Comment: Apologies for being dense, but the layout you described doesn't make sense. You have two HTML tables side by side, ok, but what's with the six rows to the right? Are they supposed to be HTML table rows (TR)? Or are they rows of data that need to be laid out in such a fashion? Maybe you could provide either more clarity or a bit of your page layout in HTML so that it's a bit more obvious.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the formatting. There are two html tables side by side. And I should loop to generate them.

Comment: lets assume that there are 3 fields, name, quantity and date. so, there will be two html tables and i get six columns, three of each table. i will not distribute different fields to different tables. so tables are just the same, side by side, with different data on them, not the fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "container table" that will have the two side-by-side tables within so that they lay out as you desire. You didn't specify, so I have table 1 with the first half of the data, and table 2 with the second half. (It's a bit easier/more straightforward, but you can do it with only a little extra effort to have row 1 in table 1, row 2 in table 2, row 3 in table 1, row 4 in table 2, etc.)

So, starting from the array of your records obtained via GetRows (arrData in my example below), and assuming your array has them in the order (from left to right) you want them displayed:

```
Response.Write "<table><tr><td>"
dim intLastRow
intLastRow = ubound(arrData, 2)
dim intBreakPoint
intBreakPoint = fix(intLastRow/2)
dim intSecondStartPoint = intBreakPoint + 1
Response.Write "<table>"
dim i
for i = 0 to intBreakPoint
    Response.Write "<tr><td>" & arrData(0, i) & "</td><td>" & arrData(1, i) & "</td><td>" & arrData(2, i) & "</td></tr>"
next
Response.Write "</table>"
if intLastRow > 0 then
    Response.Write "<table>"
    for i = intSecondStartPoint to intLastRow
        Response.Write "<tr><td>" & arrData(0, i) & "</td><td>" & arrData(1, i) & "</td><td>" & arrData(2, i) & "</td></tr>"
    next
    Response.Write "</table>"
end if
Response.Write "</td></tr></table>"
```

Comment: I first time here, is it enough just to mark as answer?

Comment: Yep. You can't upvote it (because it was of course brilliant... :-) until you gain a bit more reputation. Glad to be of help.

Comment: BTW, I did make a tiny change to the second loop -- I realized I was leaving an open table out there in the case of only one item being returned. I've edited the solution and you should incorporate it. (It's the Response.Write immediately before the if intLastRow > 0 check, and I inserted an additional Response.Write immediately afterward.)